# isortCol_0 and orderDir_0 eqivalent in Datatables 1.10 version

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to understand how to get column index and sorting (asc or desc) in java but I am not getting equivalent code. I referred to their web site for sending parameter but do not understand how exactly to get column index and sorting. Please see [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

```
    String sStart = request.getParameter("start");
    String sAmount = request.getParameter("length");
    String sEcho = request.getParameter("draw");
    String sCol = request.getParameter("isortCol_0"); //  columun name
    String sdir = request.getParameter("orderDir_0"); // asc or desc
    String searchTerm = request.getParameter("search");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is available in 1.10 version too.
In your first call it won't passed by default. Once you change the order of column you will see that in action.
Means from 1.10 you have to use isset($_REQUEST['iSortTitle_0']) and sort order parameters.